# Как можно хранить переменную в кеше - Android JAVA?

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно сделать такую тему, но не знаю с чего начать( Уже несколько дней пытаюсь найти решение.

Задача:
Когда я первый раз захожу в приложение и прохожу слайд, то после этого меня кидает на экран регистрации, если я выйду с приложения не закончив регистрацию, то если пользователь снова зайдет в приложение и все таки решит зарегистрироваться, то ему не придется заново проходить слайд. Надо чтобы его сразу кинуло на регистрацию, а если он очистит кэш или удалит приложение, то естественно заново ему проходить слайд.

Если кто-то работал с javascript, то ему будет известна такая штука как "localstorage", вот по типу такого, только в android разработке на java.

Благодарю.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage - выбирайте что вам больше нравится

Comment: Достаточно просто метку сохранять, где пользователь остановился: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

Comment: Благодарю вас за ответ, а будет ли эта метку очищаться с кэшем? @EugeneKrivenja

Comment: Нет, SharedPreferences хранятся не в кэше, а в области данных приложения. В кэш можно писать только файлами: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific#internal-create-cache

Comment: Понял, спасибо за ответ.